# As Per customer requirement i need to change the View and Edit page of My Account in Drupal7

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

[My Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aqt8L.png)

I want to add the Two fields in that Name and Mobile Number.

With that if customer wants to change his name or mobile number he has to enter the OTP as generated by us.

In Drupal core module i try create and edit i am confused.

By using hook_form_alter i can be show disabled field and all. But how to be fix with OTP functionality confusing.

With that i want to show the fields data in masked view

Please suggest me some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In drupal password field is required if you are changing email address or updating password.  as you can see under current password field description is "Enter your current password to change the E-mail address or Password."

In your case User will able to update Name and Mobile Number field without entering OTP.

If you want to no current password field use this contributed module https://www.drupal.org/project/nocurrent_pass

Comment: I want to keep the change button for changing the e-mail id and mobile no. For any of this button click by customer the otp to be generated on entering it only customer able to change mobile no and e-mailid

Comment: are you using drupal 7 or drupal 6?

Comment: I am using Drupal7 only